# How to check if two command line are equal?

Tags: c#

I have the following two commandline/run process:

```
string x = @"""C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"" /background"
string y = @"""C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"" /background"
```

We know that the command is the same, but we cannot use the `CompareTo` because it will fail (due to the different username). Following a piece of advice given to me as an answer to another question of mine, I've used the following code:

```
private static int ComputeDistance(string s, string t)
        {
            s = s.ToLower();
            t = t.ToLower();
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] distance = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
            int cost = 0;
            if (n == 0) return m;
            if (m == 0) return n;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; distance[i, 0] = i++) ;
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; distance[0, j] = j++) ;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    cost = (t.Substring(j - 1, 1) ==
                        s.Substring(i - 1, 1) ? 0 : 1);
                    distance[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1,
                    distance[i, j - 1] + 1), distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            return distance[n, m];
        }

public static float GetSimilarity(string string1, string string2)
        {
            float dis = ComputeDistance(string1, string2);
            float maxLen = string1.Length;
            if (maxLen < string2.Length)
                maxLen = string2.Length;
            if (maxLen == 0.0F)
                return 1.0F;
            else
                return 1.0F - dis / maxLen;
        }
```

Use: `Console.WriteLine(100 * MyClass.GetSimilarity(x, y));`

The two given commandline match: `93,33334`. And this is ok. But I have so many false positives! (match greather than `75%` - established by me). For example:

```
string x =  @"""C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Directory\1.exe"" -p -s";
string y = @"""C:\Users\Alice\Desktop\Directory\2.exe"" -W";
```

match: `77,27273%`. But the process and commands aren't the same!

Do you think I should do substring match (separated by `\`) for path and match one to one with the command (after the `-` or `--`, ecc.) or there is a better way?

Comment: You should probably compare the content of the executable instead of the file path, right?

Comment: So create a checksum of both exe files and use compareTo of those.

Comment: @DarkBee No, this is not related

Comment: @ShamPooSham No, the all commandline, not only the exe path

Comment: I think you should first compare the checksums of the files and then the arguments by using `String.Split(' ')` or something like that. It feels like the safest method. Just checking that the file name is the same doesn't feel very safe to me.

Comment: ^this, doing `notepad`, `notepad.exe`, `C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad` or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe` is all the same command